# Match 2 groups of numbers separated by specific characters

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a few strings, such as:

`N00E001`
`N00W001`
`N00E002`

What would be the best regex to find both groups of numbers in each string?

I'm not the best with regex. Here's what i'm currently working with: `(\d+)[W|E](\d+)`.

Comment: So is there any problem with your regex?

Comment: You don't need the `|` inside an option (`[]`).

Comment: Are the strings always isolated or are they found inside larger strings (`'blah blah N00E001 blah'`)?  Are the strings always seven characters long?  Are there strings like `'N00X001'` that you don't want to match?  If your string is always seven characters then `if s[3] in 'EW':numbers = s[1:3] + s[4:]`.  If all strings are good then you can dispense with the if-clause.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski they seem to be coordinates, so I expect them to be of the form [NS]xx[WE]xxx where x is an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"(\d+)[W|E](\d+)"
```

would also match `"N00|001"`.

So

```
"(\d+)[WE](\d+)"
```

should do fine.

If you have always the exact same format, you could use a more restrictive regex :

```
"\A[NS]\d{2}[WE]\d{3}\Z"
```

This would match :

- a N or a S
- followed by 2 digits
- followed by E or W
- followed by 3 digits

The whole match should be the complete string. `"Location N00W001"` wouldn't match, for example.

## Test

```
import re

strings = ["N00E001", "N00W001", "N00E002"]

pattern = re.compile("\A[NS]\d{2}[WE]\d{3}\Z")

print all(pattern.match(string) for string in strings)
# True
```